# MySQL InnoDB Text Search Options

Tags: mysql, innodb, full-text-search, myisam

Knowing full well that my InnoDB tables don't support FULLTEXT searches, I'm wondering what my alternatives are for searching text in tables ? Is the performance *that* bad when using LIKE ?

I see a lot of suggestions saying to make a copy of the InnoDB table in question in a MYISAM table, and then run queries against THAT table and match keys between the two and I just don't know that that's a pretty solution.

I'm not opposed to using some 3rd party solution, I'm not a huge fan of that though. I'd like to explore more of what MySQL can do on its own.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to do it *right* you probably should go with [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) from the very start.**

1. it will allow you to keep your table structure.
2. you'll have a huge performance boost (think ahead)
3. you'll get access to [a lot of fancy search functions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-apache-lucenesearch/index.html)

Both Lucene and Sphinx scale amazingly well (Lucene powers Wikipedia and Digg / Sphinx powers Slashdot)

Comment: Yeah judging from the amount of chat about Lucene, it looks like my best bet. Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 1):

Using LIKE can only use an index when there is no leading %.  It will be a huge performance hit to do LIKE '%foo%' on a large table.  If I were you, I'd look into using [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com).  It has the ability to build its index by slurping data out of MySQL using a query that you provide.  It's pretty straightforward and was designed to solve your exact problem.

There's also solr which is an http wrapper around lucene, but I find sphinx to be a little more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I as others have i would urge use of Lucene, Sphinx or Solr.

However if these are out and your requirements are simple I've used the steps [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/askeet/1_0/en/21) to build **simple** search capability on a number projects in the past.

That link is for Symfony/PHP but you can apply the concepts to any language and application structure assuming there is an implementation of a stemming algorithm available. However, if you dont use a data access pattern where you can hook in to update the index when a record is updated its not as easily doable.

Also a couple downsides are that if you want a single index table but need to index multiple tables you either have to emulate referential integrity in your DAL, or add a fk column for each different table you want to index. Im not sure what youre trying to do so that may rule it out entirely.