# MYSQL innodb fulltext search not showing all results

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, innodb

I have mysql innodb database which contains information collected from several sources, which are written in Serbian. Some of text contains latin characters, some not for same word.

I have problems like this

Ćuprija
Cuprija

represents same word, and when I do fulltext search I must specify do I need to find Ćuprija or Cuprija, is there some settings how should I make selection for both results?

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381186/fulltext-search-with-innodb?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048128/mysql-innodb-text-search-options?rq=1

Comment: innodb is now supporting full text search, in that articles they are searching for alternatives.

Comment: Can you please tell us the collation for the columns you're searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the column's collation to `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci`

With `utf8_bin`, those two words are treated differently.  With any `_ci` collation, case and accents are ignored.

Comment: When I try to change collation to utf8_general_ci I get message #1283 - Column 'tekst' cannot be part of FULLTEXT index

Comment: I have removed indexes, changed collation and recreated indexes, now it work. Thank you Rick James